# I want to solve this problem. What's the point of not getting a price?

Tags: jsp

**addSchedule.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=euc-kr" session="true" %>
<%@ page import="book.ch9.*,book.ch9.CharConversion,java.io.*" %>
<%request.setCharacterEncoding("euc-kr"); %>
<jsp:useBean id="schDb" class="book.ch9.scheduleFileDb" scope="application" />

<html>
<head>
<title>addSchedule.jsp</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">

<%  
    User user = (User)session.getValue("user");

    String id = user.getUserId();
    String day = request.getParameter("day");
    String hour = request.getParameter("hour");
    String schedule = request.getParameter("schedule");     
    String korSchedule = CharConversion.E2K(schedule);

    int index = schDb.getIndex();       

    try{    
        schDb.add(id,day,hour,korSchedule);         
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(out));
        return;
    }
%>

<jsp:forward page="welcome.jsp">
<jsp:param name="schedule" value="<%=korSchedule %>"/> 
</jsp:forward>

</body>

</body>
</html>
```

As shown in the picture, String id = user.getUserId(); I don't know why there is an error here.

I searched hard, but I couldn't find any answers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXilA.png)

Comment: Please post text as text, not as links to images of text.

Answer (score 0):

As it is shown, you have a `NullPointerException`. Consider to verify where you store your session attributes. Then, try getting your sessions attributes this way :

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
User user = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
```